# Is there any difference in variable scope when declare a variable starting by underscore in PHP?

Tags: php

what is the difference of declaring a property in a class (in PHP) as :

$_city;

or

$city;

is there a difference in variable scope when start naming by underscore?

thanks,

Comment: No. Having underscore in front of a variable name is just a *naming convention* which some people prefer to use for Private variables. But unless you explicitly specify `private` keyword in front of variable declaration, it would not make them private by themselves

Comment: There is no difference, just naming convention. According to PSR-2 standard it shouldn't be done anymore: "Property names SHOULD NOT be prefixed with a single underscore to indicate protected or private visibility."